# Using the BBM SDK in a midlet application blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, sdk, midlet

I have a running midlet application (for blackberry) and want to incorporate a feature "Share on BBM" which allows the user to share the download link of my app to their BBM contacts

I am using the Blackberry Plugin for eclipse.

Sending a download invitation in a UIApplication can be accomplished if you follow BBM SDK developers manual but they mention nothing about accomplishing this for a midlet

The main problem I am having is that you can't display the screen that prompts for the download because it is a midelt

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry Messenger SDK :app download invite (in a MIDlet)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391352/blackberry-messenger-sdk-app-download-invite-in-a-midlet)