# Blackberry Messenger SDK :app download invite (in a MIDlet)

Tags: blackberry, java-me, sdk, midlet

I have a MIDlet application already running.

I am just wondering if I can take advantage of the BBM SDK features in my already running midlet app.

More specifically, I would like to be able to send an invite to download my app to my bbm contacts. I know this can be accomplished in a blackberry UIApplication, but is it possible for MIDlets?

Your reply is highly appreciated!

Thanks